# How to get the most recent entry from a database table for a certain user

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table that displays information on users in a database:

```
$query = "SELECT reviews2_users.id AS IDUSER,
                            signature,
                            user,
                            email,
                            address,
                            COUNT(reviews2_reviews.id) AS COUNTER
            FROM reviews2_users LEFT JOIN reviews2_reviews ON (reviews2_users.id = reviews2_reviews.id_user)
            GROUP BY reviews2_users.id
            ORDER BY COUNTER DESC";
```

For every user in the table I'd like to show the date of the LATEST entry that they've made into the database.

I tried this but it doesn't work (and I'm not very good with databse/mysql):

```
$query = "SELECT reviews2_users.id AS IDUSER,
                            signature,
                            user,
                            email,
                            address,
                            COUNT(reviews2_reviews.id) AS COUNTER
            FROM reviews2_users LEFT JOIN reviews2_reviews ON (reviews2_users.id = reviews2_reviews.id_user)
                            AND LEFT JOIN reviews2_reviews ON max(reviews2_reviews.date)
            GROUP BY reviews2_users.id
            ORDER BY COUNTER DESC";
```

Could somebody help me out on this?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add `MAX(date)` to first query:

```
$query = "
SELECT reviews2_users.id AS IDUSER
     , signature
     , user
     , email
     , address
     , COUNT(reviews2_reviews.id) AS COUNTER
     , MAX(reviews2_reviews.date) as date
  FROM reviews2_users 
  LEFT 
  JOIN reviews2_reviews 
    ON (reviews2_users.id = reviews2_reviews.id_user)
 GROUP 
    BY reviews2_users.id
 ORDER 
    BY COUNTER DESC
";
```

Comment: thank you so much Omer... I've upvoted and marked your answer as the correct one